# MySQL JSON Handling -> and ->> operators don't work

Tags: json, syntax, mariadb, operator-keyword

I have a question.

I am trying to apply the following query in an arrow form in mariaDB to be used by php.

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`Purpose Link`,"$.id[0]")) AS 'Item ID' FROM `financial_instruments` WHERE `Instrument ID` = 0;
```

As far as I understand the arrow notation form must look like the following.

```
SELECT `Purpose Link`->>"$.id[0]" AS 'Item ID' FROM `financial_instruments` WHERE `Instrument ID` = 0;
```

However the second expression doesn't work. It issues #1064 Syntax error to Maria DB sever version.
The storage engine I am using is InnoDB for the table.

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Comment: _Small Point_ MySQL and mariaDB are similar but not the same, its best to tag mariaDB if that is what you are actually using

Comment: To be able to help, we would need to see the schema and at least an example of the data in that column. See ... Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Apologies, I am using XAMPP. While the control panel displays that MySQL is in use, when accessing the PhpMyAdmin Dashboard it displays that Maria DB is in use. Maria doesn't support the extract (-> and its unquoted counterpart ->>) JSON operator as MySQL does. Cursory research yields that while the operators are intended to be implemented not just as aliases, but as stand alone syntax, there hasn't been progress in that direction for the past 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

Using XAMPP v.3.2.4. While the control panel displays that MySQL is in use, when accessing the PhpMyAdmin Dashboard it displays that Maria DB is actually in use. Maria doesn't support the extract (-> and its unquoted counterpart ->>) JSON operator as MySQL does. Cursory research yields that while the operators are intended to be implemented not just as aliases, but as stand alone syntax, there hasn't been progress in that direction for the past 3 years.